# Using Web URL call elements on a table visual with a USERELATIONSHIP measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, hyperlink, dax, relational-database

**This is a quite complex issue to explain, so let me know if my explanation is not clear enough.**

I have a 3 tables:

1. **Application**: which shows information about various applications (ex. PowerPoint has a description, the version, etc..)

- PK = *Application_ID*

2. **Interfaces**: which shows what applications are talking to each other (ex. 'PowerPoint to Word' is 1 Interface that has 2 applications: 'PowerPoint': the input & 'Word': the output)

- PK: *Interface_ID*
- FK: *Input_ID* & *Output_ID*

3. **Dataflows**: which shows what data is being sent between the interfaces (ex. PowerPoint to Word has 5 dataflows, Word to PowerPoint has 2 dataflows)

- PK: *Dataflow_ID*
- FK: *Interface_ID*

Thus, these are the relationships:

- 'Application'[*Application_ID*] = 'Interface'[*Input_ID*]
- 'Application'[*Application_ID*] = 'Interface'[*Output_ID*]
- 'Interfaces'[*Interface_ID*] = 'Dataflow'[Interface_ID]

But with Power BI, you are unable to have an active relationship between two foreign keys and a primary key (i.e. *Input_ID* & *Output_ID*), so I had to create these measures to establish these relationships:

1. `Count_Interface1 = DISTINCTCOUNT('Interfaces'[ID])`
2. `Count_Interface2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Interfaces'[ID]),USERELATIONSHIP(' Application'[Id],'Interfaces'[Output_Id]))`

I have a dashboard that contains two table visuals: one that shows the Input Interfaces and one that shows the Output Interfaces. (For example, if I filtered by PowerPoint, the input table would show 'PowerPoint to Word', 'PowerPoint to Excel', etc... whereas the output table would show 'Word to PowerPoint', 'Access to PowerPoint').

The Input Interfaces table uses the Count_Interface1 measure.
The Output Interfaces table uses the Count_Interface2 measure.

The problem I am running into, is when trying to use Call Elements to add hyperlinks to the interface names and I believe the issue is with the **USERELATIONSHIP** measure.

In the Interfaces table I have an [*Interface_link*] field. When I use call elements in the Input Interfaces table visual to add the [*Interface_link*] it successfully creates a hyper link on the interfaces. (For example, 'PowerPoint to Word' & 'PowerPoint to Excel' all have hyperlinks that work in the table visual)

When I try this with the Output Interfaces table visual, the links associated with the Output interfaces to not attach as hyperlinks. (For example, 'Word to PowerPoint' & 'Access to PowerPoint' do NOT have hyperlinks). But if I add the [*Interface_link*] as an additional field in the Output Interfaces table visual it successfully populates, but I do not want the link as a URL icon in a separate column, I want it as a hyperlink on the Interface name.

I believe this is happening due to the **USERELATIONSHIP** measure, but do not know how to adjust it, to get the links to add as hyperlinks.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to use Call Elements to add hyperlinks to the interface names"?

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this, I created a measure similar to **Count_Interface2**:

```
Count_Interface2_Link = CALCULATE(MAX('Interfaces'[Dataflow_Filter]),USERELATIONSHIP(' Interfaces'[Output_Id],'Application'[Id]))
```

**Dataflow_Filter** being my link column.

Then under Visualizations --> Call Elements --> Apply Settings to (whatever column you want the links attached to) --> Web URL On --> Field based on **Count_Interface2_Link**